# How to browse an enumeration classe?

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

I have an enumeration Class and I want to use the values in it in order to populate a ComboBox.

The enum class :

```
public enum Drink {
    Water, Milk, Coffee, Thea, wine
}
```

The controller class :

```
@FXML
private JFXComboBox DrinkComboBox;

private void SetComboBox(JFXComboBox DrinkComboBox)
{
    // fill this.DrinkComboBox with value of enum Drink
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `enum` has a `values()` method that returns an array containing all values of the enum.

So all you need is

```
@FXML
private JFXComboBox<Drink> drinkComboBox;

private void SetComboBox() {
   this.drinkComboBox.getItems().setAll(Drink.values());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to iterate over the enums:

```
for (Drink drink : Drink.values()) {
   //do things with drink
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has some great tutorials on enums. [Enum Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html). The the .value() method should give you what you want.